# pass memoryview to win32.ReadFile for Pyserial readinto() function

Tags: python, pyserial

I want to create a proper readinto function for the pyserial package (for windows). pyserial implements readinto() by calling read() which defeats the purpose of readinto. Adapting the [existing read() function](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/blob/master/serial/serialwin32.py) seemed straightforward to accept a memoryview:

```py
def serial_read_into(serial_object, buf, size) -> int:
    if not serial_object.is_open:
        raise PortNotOpenError()
    
    if size == 0:
        return 0
    
    win32.ResetEvent(serial_object._overlapped_read.hEvent)
    flags = win32.DWORD()
    comstat = win32.COMSTAT()
    if not win32.ClearCommError(serial_object._port_handle, ctypes.byref(flags), ctypes.byref(comstat)):
        raise SerialException("ClearCommError failed ({!r})".format(ctypes.WinError()))
    
    length = min(comstat.cbInQue, size) if serial_object.timeout == 0 else size
    
    if length == 0:
        return 0
    # buf = ctypes.create_string_buffer(n) <---- Note this in the read() implementation
    rc = win32.DWORD()
    read_ok = win32.ReadFile(
        serial_object._port_handle,
        buf,
        size,
        ctypes.byref(rc),
        ctypes.byref(serial_object._overlapped_read))
    if not read_ok and win32.GetLastError() not in (win32.ERROR_SUCCESS, win32.ERROR_IO_PENDING):
        raise SerialException("ReadFile failed ({!r})".format(ctypes.WinError()))
    
    result_ok = win32.GetOverlappedResult(
        serial_object._port_handle,
        ctypes.byref(serial_object._overlapped_read),
        ctypes.byref(rc),
        True)
    
    if not result_ok:
        if win32.GetLastError() != win32.ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED:
            raise SerialException("GetOverlappedResult failed ({!r})".format(ctypes.WinError()))
    
    
    read = rc.value
    return read
```

**Problem**: The win32.ReadFile() function does not accept a memoryview. How can I pass the memoryview to the win32.ReadFile() function?
The error is
`ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type`

I have a memoryview, because I want to receive into a multiprocessing.SharedMemory region without extra copying.

Answer (score 0):

The following obtains a char* from the memoryview, which works with the win32.ReadFile call:
`dst = (ctypes.c_char * size).from_buffer(buf)`